# Action Listener looped through multiple times on one click

Tags: java, actionlistener

For some reason when I click the GO button the MainScreenHandler loops through twice. Note this does not happen on the first click but happens on subsequent clicks.

I believe the issue is because I change the action listener to ChoiceHandler after the first click and then change it back to MainScreenHandler.

I really have no idea why this is.

I'm new to Java and trying to write an adventure game with a GUI. Any other tips would be appreciated too.

Here is the MainGameScreen class.

```
package textAdvTwo;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class MainGameScreen {
    JFrame window;
    Container con;
    ImageIcon badge;
    JPanel titleNamePanel, startButtonPanel, mainTextPanel, choiceButtonPanel,
            infoPanel, badgeLabelPanel, warningTextPanel;
    JLabel titleNameLabel, locationLabel, locationLabelNumber, inventoryLabel,
            inventoryLabelName, badgeLabel, warningLabel;
    Font titleFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 40);
    Font normalFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 18);
    Font largerFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 24);
    Font mainTextFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 28);
    JButton startButton, goButton, lookButton, searchButton, inventoryButton,
            giveButton, talkButton, dropButton, unknownButton;
    JTextArea mainTextArea, warningTextArea;
    int playerHP, monsterHP, silverRing;
    String weapon, position;
    GameFlow gameFlow = new GameFlow();
    JButton[] buttons = new JButton[8];

    TitleScreenHandler tsHandler = new TitleScreenHandler();
    MainGameScreenHandler choiceHandler = new MainGameScreenHandler();
    ItemChoiceHandler itemChoiceHandler = new ItemChoiceHandler();

    public MainGameScreen() {

        window = new JFrame();
        window.setSize(800, 600);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        window.setLayout(null);
        con = window.getContentPane();

        titleNamePanel = new JPanel();
        titleNamePanel.setBounds(100, 450, 600, 150);
        titleNamePanel.setBackground(Color.black);
        titleNameLabel = new JLabel("A day in the life of Rafa Benitez...");
        titleNameLabel.setForeground(Color.white);
        titleNameLabel.setFont(titleFont);

        badge = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("badge.jpg"));
        badgeLabel = new JLabel(badge);

        badgeLabelPanel = new JPanel();
        badgeLabelPanel.setBounds(200, 0, 400, 400);
        badgeLabelPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        badgeLabelPanel.add(badgeLabel);

        startButtonPanel = new JPanel();
        startButtonPanel.setBounds(300, 400, 200, 100);
        startButtonPanel.setBackground(Color.black);

        startButton = new JButton("START");
        startButton.addActionListener(tsHandler);
        startButton.setForeground(Color.black);
        startButton.setFont(normalFont);

        startButton.setFocusPainted(false);

        titleNamePanel.add(titleNameLabel);
        startButtonPanel.add(startButton);

        con.add(badgeLabelPanel);
        con.add(titleNamePanel);
        con.add(startButtonPanel);
        window.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void createGameScreen() {

        titleNamePanel.setVisible(false);
        startButtonPanel.setVisible(false);
        badgeLabelPanel.setVisible(false);

        mainTextPanel = new JPanel();
        mainTextPanel.setBounds(100, 130, 600, 200);
        mainTextPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
        con.add(mainTextPanel);

        warningTextPanel = new JPanel();
        warningTextPanel.setBounds(300, 25, 500, 50);
        warningTextPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
        con.add(warningTextPanel);

        mainTextArea = new JTextArea();
        mainTextArea.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 200);
        mainTextArea.setBackground(Color.black);
        mainTextArea.setForeground(Color.white);
        mainTextArea.setFont(mainTextFont);
        mainTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
        mainTextArea.setText(mainTextDesc(gameFlow.locations, gameFlow.rafa,
                gameFlow.characs));
        mainTextPanel.add(mainTextArea);

        warningTextArea = new JTextArea();
        warningTextArea.setBounds(300, 25, 500, 50);
        warningTextArea.setBackground(Color.black);
        warningTextArea.setForeground(Color.red);
        warningTextArea.setFont(normalFont);
        warningTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
        warningTextPanel.add(warningTextArea);

        choiceButtonPanel = new JPanel();
        choiceButtonPanel.setBounds(250, 400, 300, 150);
        choiceButtonPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
        choiceButtonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2));
        con.add(choiceButtonPanel);

        goButton = new JButton();
        goButton.setText("GO");
        goButton.setForeground(Color.black);
        goButton.setFont(normalFont);
        goButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        goButton.addActionListener(choiceHandler);
        goButton.setActionCommand("go");
        buttons[0] = goButton;
        choiceButtonPanel.add(goButton);
        lookButton = new JButton();
        lookButton.setText("LOOK");
        lookButton.setForeground(Color.black);
        lookButton.setFont(normalFont);
        lookButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        lookButton.addActionListener(choiceHandler);
        lookButton.setActionCommand("look");
        buttons[1] = lookButton;
        choiceButtonPanel.add(lookButton);
        searchButton = new JButton();
        searchButton.setText("SEARCH");
        searchButton.setForeground(Color.black);
        searchButton.setFont(normalFont);
        searchButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        searchButton.addActionListener(choiceHandler);
        searchButton.setActionCommand("search");
        buttons[2] = searchButton;
        choiceButtonPanel.add(searchButton);
        inventoryButton = new JButton();
        inventoryButton.setText("INVENTORY");
        inventoryButton.setForeground(Color.black);
        inventoryButton.setFont(normalFont);
        inventoryButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        inventoryButton.addActionListener(choiceHandler);
        inventoryButton.setActionCommand("inventory");
        buttons[3] = inventoryButton;
        choiceButtonPanel.add(inventoryButton);
        giveButton = new JButton();
        giveButton.setText("GIVE");
        giveButton.setForeground(Color.black);
        giveButton.setFont(normalFont);
        giveButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        giveButton.addActionListener(choiceHandler);
        giveButton.setActionCommand("give");
        buttons[4] = giveButton;
        choiceButtonPanel.add(giveButton);
        talkButton = new JButton();
        talkButton.setText("TALK");
        talkButton.setForeground(Color.black);
        talkButton.setFont(normalFont);
        talkButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        talkButton.addActionListener(choiceHandler);
        talkButton.setActionCommand("talk");
        buttons[5] = talkButton;
        choiceButtonPanel.add(talkButton);
        dropButton = new JButton();
        dropButton.setText("DROP");
        dropButton.setForeground(Color.black);
        dropButton.setFont(normalFont);
        dropButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        dropButton.addActionListener(choiceHandler);
        dropButton.setActionCommand("drop");
        buttons[6] = dropButton;
        choiceButtonPanel.add(dropButton);
        unknownButton = new JButton();
        unknownButton.setText("UNKNOWN");
        unknownButton.setForeground(Color.black);
        unknownButton.setFont(normalFont);
        unknownButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        unknownButton.addActionListener(choiceHandler);
        unknownButton.setActionCommand("unknown");
        buttons[7] = unknownButton;
        choiceButtonPanel.add(unknownButton);

        infoPanel = new JPanel();
        infoPanel.setBounds(100, 15, 350, 90);
        infoPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
        infoPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));
        con.add(infoPanel);
        locationLabel = new JLabel("Location:");
        locationLabel.setFont(normalFont);
        locationLabel.setForeground(Color.white);
        infoPanel.add(locationLabel);
        locationLabelNumber = new JLabel();
        locationLabelNumber.setFont(largerFont);
        locationLabelNumber.setForeground(Color.blue);
        locationLabelNumber.setText(getLocation(gameFlow.locations,
                gameFlow.rafa));
        infoPanel.add(locationLabelNumber);


    }
    public void refreshMainScreen(){
        goButton.setText("GO");
        goButton.setActionCommand("go");
        goButton.addActionListener(choiceHandler);
        lookButton.setText("LOOK");
        lookButton.setActionCommand("look");
        lookButton.addActionListener(choiceHandler);
        searchButton.setText("SEARCH");
        searchButton.setActionCommand("search");
        searchButton.addActionListener(choiceHandler);
        inventoryButton.setText("INVENTORY");
        inventoryButton.setActionCommand("inventory");
        inventoryButton.addActionListener(choiceHandler);
        giveButton.setText("GIVE");
        giveButton.setActionCommand("give");
        giveButton.addActionListener(choiceHandler);
        talkButton.setText("TALK");
        talkButton.setActionCommand("talk");
        talkButton.addActionListener(choiceHandler);
        dropButton.setText("DROP");
        dropButton.setActionCommand("drop");
        dropButton.addActionListener(choiceHandler);
        unknownButton.setText("UNKNOWN");
        unknownButton.setActionCommand("unknown");
        unknownButton.addActionListener(choiceHandler);
        mainTextArea.setText(mainTextDesc(gameFlow.locations, gameFlow.rafa,
                gameFlow.characs));
        locationLabelNumber.setText(getLocation(gameFlow.locations,
                gameFlow.rafa));
        /*inventoryLabelName.setText(inventoryLabel(gameFlow.rafa));*/
    }

    public class TitleScreenHandler implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            createGameScreen();
        }

    }
    public class ItemChoiceHandler implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("itemAL");
            String choice = e.getActionCommand();
            gameFlow.rafa.inventory.get(Integer.parseInt(choice)).setX(gameFlow.rafa.getX());
            gameFlow.rafa.inventory.get(Integer.parseInt(choice)).setY(gameFlow.rafa.getY());
            gameFlow.items.add(gameFlow.rafa.inventory.get(Integer.parseInt(choice)));
            gameFlow.rafa.inventory.remove(Integer.parseInt(choice));
            for(int i = 0; i<gameFlow.rafa.inventory.size(); i++){
                buttons[i].removeActionListener(itemChoiceHandler);
                }

            refreshMainScreen();
        }

    }

    public class MainGameScreenHandler implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String choice = e.getActionCommand();

            if (choice.equals("go")) {
                go();
                System.out.println("go");
            } else if (choice.equals("look")) {
                refreshMainScreen();
            } else if (choice.equals("search")) {
                search();
            } else if (choice.equals("inventory")) {
                inventory(gameFlow.rafa);
            } else if (choice.equals("give")) {

            } else if (choice.equals("talk")) {
                System.out.println("talk");
            } else if (choice.equals("drop")) {
                drop(gameFlow.rafa);
            } else if (choice.equals("unknown")) {
                System.out.println("unknown");
            } else if (choice.equals("north")){
                if(gameFlow.rafa.x > 0){
                    gameFlow.rafa.moveNorth();
                    System.out.println("north");
                    warningTextArea.setText("");
                }
                else{
                    warningTextArea.setText("You can't move that way.");
                }
                refreshMainScreen();
            } else if (choice.equals("east")){
                if(gameFlow.rafa.y < 2){
                    gameFlow.rafa.moveEast();
                    warningTextArea.setText("");
                }
                else{
                    warningTextArea.setText("You can't move that way.");
                }
                refreshMainScreen();
            } else if (choice.equals("west")){
                if(gameFlow.rafa.y > 0){
                    gameFlow.rafa.moveWest();
                    warningTextArea.setText("");
                }
                else{
                    warningTextArea.setText("You can't move that way.");
                }
                refreshMainScreen();
            } else if (choice.equals("south")){
                if(gameFlow.rafa.x < 2){
                    gameFlow.rafa.moveSouth();
                    System.out.println("south");
                    warningTextArea.setText("");
                }
                else{
                    warningTextArea.setText("You can't move that way.");
                }
                refreshMainScreen();
            }
            }


        }

    public void drop(Rafa rafa){
        String buttonNames[] = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7"};
        mainTextArea.setText("What do you want to drop?");
        if(rafa.inventory.size() == 0){
            mainTextArea.setText("You have nothing to drop!");
        }
        else{
            for(int i = 0; i<rafa.inventory.size(); i++){
                buttons[i].setText(rafa.inventory.get(i).getName());        
                buttons[i].setActionCommand(buttonNames[i]);
                buttons[i].removeActionListener(choiceHandler);
                buttons[i].addActionListener(itemChoiceHandler);
                }
            for(int j = rafa.inventory.size(); j<8; j++){
                    buttons[j].setText("");
                }
            }
        }



    public void search() {
        Items itemFound = searchRoom(gameFlow.rafa, gameFlow.items);
        if (itemFound != null) {
            gameFlow.rafa.inventory.add(itemFound);
            gameFlow.items.remove(itemFound);
            mainTextArea.setText(itemFound.firstTimeDesc);
        } else {
            mainTextArea.setText("Your search reveals nothing new.");
        }
    }

    public Items searchRoom(Rafa rafa, ArrayList<Items> items) {
        Items item = null;
        for (Items it : items) {
            if (it.getX() == rafa.getX() && it.getY() == rafa.getY()) {
                item = it;
            }
        }
        return item;
    }

    public String getLocation(Locations[][] locations, Rafa rafa) {
        return locations[rafa.getX()][rafa.getY()].getName();
    }

    public String mainTextDesc(Locations[][] locations, Rafa rafa,
            ArrayList<NonPlayingCharac> characs) {
        String desc = "";
        if (whoIsInRoom(rafa, characs).size() == 0) {
            desc += locations[rafa.getX()][rafa.getY()].getDesc();
        } else {
            String inRoom = "";
            for (NonPlayingCharac person : whoIsInRoom(rafa, characs)) {
                if (person == null) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    inRoom += person.getFullName() + "\n";
                }
                desc += locations[rafa.getX()][rafa.getY()].getDesc()
                        + "\n\nIn the room you also see\n" + inRoom;
            }
        }
        return desc;
    }

    public ArrayList<NonPlayingCharac> whoIsInRoom(Rafa rafa,
            ArrayList<NonPlayingCharac> characs) {
        ArrayList<NonPlayingCharac> inRoom = new ArrayList<NonPlayingCharac>();
        for (NonPlayingCharac person : characs) {

            if (person.getX() == rafa.getX() && person.getY() == rafa.getY()) {
                inRoom.add(person);
            }
        }
        return inRoom;
    }

    public void inventory(Rafa rafa) {
        String invent = "You are carrying:\n";
        if (rafa.inventory.size() != 0) {
            for (Items item : rafa.inventory) {
                invent += item.name + ", " + item.description + "\n";
            }
        } else {
            invent += "nothing.";
        }
        mainTextArea.setText(invent);
    }

    public String inventoryLabel(Rafa rafa) {
        String inventory = "";
        if (rafa.inventory.size() != 0) {
            for (Items item : rafa.inventory) {
                inventory += "\n" + item.name ;
            }
        } else {
            inventory = "Nothing.";
        }
        return inventory;
    }

    public void go() {
        mainTextArea.setText("Which direction?");
        goButton.setText("NORTH");
        goButton.setActionCommand("north");
        searchButton.setText("EAST");
        searchButton.setActionCommand("east");
        giveButton.setText("WEST");
        giveButton.setActionCommand("west");
        dropButton.setText("SOUTH");
        dropButton.setActionCommand("south");
        lookButton.setText("");
        inventoryButton.setText("");
        talkButton.setText("");
        unknownButton.setText("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a lot of adding and removing of action listeners, which can very easily lead to mistakes such as this. The listeners are stored in a list, so there are no safety checks for adding duplicates, or ensuring there is only one listener assigned to the button.

In this case, from a brief perusal of your code it appears the "GO" button eventually ends up with two action listeners assigned to it. That means the first time it's fine, but then code is run that adds another listener. The next time you press the button, both listeners fire.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I thought that I was removing the action listeners correctly but I guess not. I'll try creating a new screen with new buttons when the user has to make a second choice (ie. GO then DIRECTION)